# Rubber Components Rejuvenation Products & Experience

Tags: rubber

Are rubber rejuvenation products worth it? Do they work/improve the lifespan of the component?

Several years back I saw a Scotty Kilmer video using ATP AT-205 for several car rubber components. The product itself does state - Rejuivinates all rubber seals & gaskets in engines, transmissions, power steering, differentials and hydraulic systems. Does not contain petroleum distillates, will not over-swell or breakdown seals.

[image: ATP AT-205]

Being based in the UK I am unable to get it, without spending a fortune. Few weeks back I came across a video with someone using 303 Aerospace Protectant, this being readily available in the UK.

[image: 303 Aerospace Protectant]

Allegedly this works similar to the ATP AT-205. The product itself does state - Great for use on a variety of surfaces such as: vinyl, leather, plastics, synthetic & natural rubber, PVC, gel coat & fibreglass.

Is there any benefit to using any such product on rubber suspension components? Tie rod rubber boots, ball joint rubber boots, CV joint rubber boots, engine mounts? I'm wondering some of these rubber components can harden over time, so wouldn't rejuvenating - potentially softening them up a bit destroy/damage them earlier?

Thanks.

Comment: Be leery of Scotty Kilmer as he hucks products for profit. Not every solution he offers is correct. Uv and exposure to road salts age rubber and plastics. Some plastics may be rejuvenated with 303 but not all. Unless suspension rubbers use polyurethane, rubbers simply age when exposed to grease and oil. Since no one has expertise in preserving exposed rubber used in suspension, 303 may need to be applied over the course of its lifetime to benefit, without proof of preserving them. Other plastics may benefit from drying out with 303; bumpers, interior plastics, etc.